# How to output only the first n lines based on occurrences of a column string

Tags: linux, awk, grep, text-parsing

I have a large file that contains ID numbers in the first column, followed by additional unique information in subsequent columns. Each ID number occurs multiple times in the file:

```
000112 3489 A-8 40984
000112 4743 A-7 94587
000112 5894 A-1 45795
000177 8347 A-2 54575
000177 5843 B-5 94342
000177 5684 A-4 76544
000177 6586 C-2 65834
000226 5679 C-2 85795
000226 5456 C-1 45876
000226 9899 A-2 56834
```

I would like to output a file containing lines for only the first two occurrences of each ID number:

```
000112 3489 A-8 40984
000112 4743 A-7 94587
000177 8347 A-2 54575
000177 5843 B-5 94342
000226 5679 C-2 85795
000226 5456 C-1 45876
```

Note that this data represents only a small portion of the input file, so a command that requires entering specific strings (ID numbers) is not what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: In what language?

Comment: In the example input (and output), all lines with a given ID are consecutive. Moreover, the IDs are sorted. You should say whether you can rely on these factors in the real input (and whether they're required in the real output).

Comment: Using a linux command (e.g. grep/uniq), and/or awk command. Let's assume that both real input and output files are not sorted in any way. The desired output is to have line information for only two of each unique ID numbers. So, (e.g.) with ref to the input above, 000112 3489 A-8 40984 and 000112 5894 A-1 45795 is as useful as the 000112 information in the output above. I think I can perform the task in 4 steps; (1) awk '!seen[$1]++' input.file > output1 (2) grep -v -F -f output1 input.file > output2 (3) awk '!seen[$1]++' output2 > output3 (4) cat output1 output3 | sort -k 1 > desired.output

Comment: Something like `awk '++seen[$1] < 3' input.txt` should do what you want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'a[$1]++ < 2' input-file
```

should do the trick.  Just read the file and increment an array indexed by the value in the first column.  If that value is less than 2, print the line.  When you see the same id the 3rd time, the index in the array will be two and the output of that line will be suppressed.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't pretty but it yields the desired output:

Step 1:

```
awk '!seen[$1]++' input.file > output1
```

Step 2:

```
grep -v -F -f output1 input.file | awk '!seen[$1]++' > output2
```

Step 3:

```
cat output1 output2 | sort -k 1 > desired.output
```